# asp.net MVC with Angular 2: routing only takes last part of URL into account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular2-routing

I've an Angular 2 application in my asp.net MVC project. I'm using Webpack as module bundler.

I've this in my index.cshtml:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>xxx</title>
    <base href="./">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading app...</app>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/inline.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/styles.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've the following routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: "apps",
    children: [
        {
            path: "",
            component: AppOverviewComponent,
        },
        {
            path: "**",
            component: PageNotFoundComponent
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: "admin",
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: "apps",
            children: [
                {
                    path: "details/:id",
                    component: AdminAppDetailsComponent
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: "",
            redirectTo: "apps",
            pathMatch: "full"
        },
        {
            path: "**",
            component: PageNotFoundComponent
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "apps",
    pathMatch: "full"
},
{
    path: "**",
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
}
];
```

And I use them:

```
    RouterModule.forRoot(
        appRoutes, 
        { enableTracing: true }
    )
```

When I navigate within the app, everything works fine.

When I navigate with the browser to for example "http://localhost/xxx/admin/apps/details/2", it goes to the PageNotFoundComponent. With tracing you can see that it is navigation to "/2" and not "admin/apps/details/2".

[image: Angular 2 Router tracing]

I've added these rewrite rules in the config file:

```
    <rule name="favicon" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?(favicon\.ico)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./dist/{R:2}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="fonts" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?(.*\.[tff|woff2|woff]+)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./dist/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="chunks" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?(.*\.chunk\.js)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./dist/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="bundles" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?(.*\.bundle\.js)(\.map)?$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./dist/{R:2}{R:3}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="assets" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?\/assets\/(.*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./assets/{R:2}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="api" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?\/api\/(.*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./api/{R:2}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="angularjs routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/$" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/api/.*$" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./" />
    </rule>
```

So it looks like the URL is going to the Angular 2 Router but it only takes the last piece of the URL? Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it a bit different. Instead of the relative URL (./), I now use a real URL that I get from the config-file. This can be configured for the different environments.

On my local machine the URL is something like : http://localhost/xxx/admin/apps/details/2

```
<add key="baseHref" value="http://localhost/xxx/"/>
```

On a server it is something like: http://server/yyy/xxx/zzz/admin/apps/details/2

```
<add key="baseHref" value="http://server/yyy/xxx/zzz/"/>
```

This is now my index.cshtml:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <script>
       var apiUrl = "@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseHref"]";
       document.write("<base href='" + apiUrl + "' />");
   </script>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>xxx</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
   <app>Loading app...</app>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/inline.bundle.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/styles.bundle.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also needed to update the rewrite rules in the config file (urls changed from './dist' to 'dist'):

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="favicon" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?(favicon\.ico)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="dist/{R:2}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="fonts" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?(.*\.[tff|woff2|woff]+)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="dist/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="chunks" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?(.*\.chunk\.js)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="dist/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="bundles" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?(.*\.bundle\.js)(\.map)?$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="dist/{R:2}{R:3}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="assets" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?\/assets\/(.*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="assets/{R:2}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="api" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*\/+)?\/api\/(.*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="api/{R:2}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="angularjs routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/$" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/api/.*$" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This way it all works so I'm happy with it.